# Cant set up ANDENGINE GLES2-AnchorCenter Examples & Extensions

Tags: andengine

I am trying to setup the GLES2-AnchorCenter in my eclipse 
Downloaded andengine , extension and examples listed in Anchor center branch .But not yet succed .

Andengine examples missing an extension named

> andengine cocosbuilder extension CC Rotating Sprite extension

But i am not able to find it anywhere.If i am missing the extension please give me a link to get the extension.

In extensions Multitouch extension shows some error with import statement

```
import org.anddev.andengine.util.SystemUtils;
```

Actually i am not able to find org.anddev package it self in andegine,

in andengine scripting extensuion it shows error with the statement

import org.andengine.util.color.Color;
What are the things I am missing. 
Do i need to install all thse extensions to get the eample get working?

Please Help me ..........

Answer (score 3):

1) Here's the [CocosBuilder Extension](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineCocosBuilderExtension/tree/GLES2-AnchorCenter).

2) `org.anddev.andengine` is an old package name. Are you using the good branch of the Multitouch extension?
It should be `import org.andengine.util.system.SystemUtils;`.

3) You may not use the good branch where there's the error with Color package.
It should be `import org.andengine.util.color.Color;`.